# Make next button pointer events none until video finish in presto player and tutor lms

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm trying to make a custom type of Lms site using WordPress, elementor, presto player and Tutor lms.
I want to disable the next button until user finish the video and it appears only when user finish watching the video.
I'm trying to force that button with this code in JS:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var media = document.querySelector('video');
      media.addEventListener("ended", BtnVisible); 
    function BtnVisible(){ const btnVisible = document.getElementsByClassName("tutor-next-previous-pagination-wrap"); console.log(btnVisible); btnVisible[0].style.visibility = "visible"; }; 
  
    }
  );
</script>
```

I expect to have the button "next" disabled and have a countdown of video on top it until the video finish.